# How to handle timeouts in a REST Client when calling methods with side-effect

Tags: rest, client-server

Let's say we have a REST client with some UI that lists items it GETs from the server. The server also exposes some REST methods to manipulate the items (POST / PUT).

Now the user triggers one of those calls that are supposed to change the data on the server side. The UI will reflect the server state change, if the call was successful.

- But what are good strategies to handle the situation when the server is not available?
- What is a reasonable timeout lengths (especially in a 3G / Cloud setup)?
- How do you handle the timeout in the client, considering the fact that the client can't tell whether the operation succeeded or not?
- Are there any common patterns to solve that, other than a complete client termination (and subsequent restart)?

Answer (score 0):

1. This will be application specific. You need to decide what makes the most sense in your usage case.
2. Perhaps start with a timeout similar to that of the the default PHP session of 24 minutes. Adjust as necessary based on testing.
3. Do you have server and client mixed up here? If so the server cannot tell if the client times out other than reaching the end of a session. The client can always query the server for a progress update.
4. This one is a little general to provide an answer for.